# How Spring @Configuration is discovered?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In a web app using xml configuration you specify in the `web.xml` where your application context is so Spring can create your beans. Using `@Configuration` does it scan all the packages looking for this annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `@ComponentScan` annotation with `@Configuration` to specify base package where spring will look to create beans.

Below code specify how to use `@ComponentScan` annotation at class level.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "basepackageName", 
               excludeFilters = 
                   @ComponentScan.Filter(value = Controller.class, 
                                         type = FilterType.ANNOTATION)
```

Also implements WebApplicationInitializer interface and onStartup() of it initialize  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext and register your configuration class as shown below

`AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
context.register(Configuration.class);`

here Configuration class is containing @Configuration. –

Comment: but how @Configuration gets scanned in the first place?

Comment: use WebApplicationInitializer interface and override its onStartup(). Where you have to initialize AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext  that instruct spring to use annotation based configuration. like AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
context.register(Configuration.class); here Configuration class is containing @Configuration.

Comment: Instead of dumping code in comments, add them to the answer.

Comment: I see and I guess WebApplicationInitializer is implemented using the Servlet container api so it can be hooked during startup

Comment: Yes WebApplicationInitializer  is using the Servet container api.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the package to scan in your spring configuration file.

Like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="your.package" />

</beans>
```

Comment: So at least I have to have that in xml? Then It doesn't make sense to me to have @ComponentScan annotation, it would be reduntant

Comment: If you use @ComponentScan then tyou don't  need the xml configuration. You did not tell you where using it :)

Comment: But if you use @ComponentScan how it gets discovered in the first place?

Comment: You need to implement the WebApplicationInitializer interface